# Salesforce - Spring ’21 - Organization-Wide Email Adresses

Tags: email, administration, release, org-wide-defaults

Testing Customize your default no-reply Address

Added the email address under  Setup > Organization-Wide Addresses > Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Addresses

and Email is verified now

[image]

And Click Enable Test Run in Setup > Release Updates > Use a Default No-Reply Address as System Address for Case Email Notifications

When i tested this feature it still showing norely@salesforce.com

**Note:** Support Settings --> select Send Notifications from System Address tried with enable and disable still getting noreply@salesforce.com

Can you help me on what i am missing here

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_service_case_management_noreply.htm&type=5&release=230

Comment: I have followed the steps mentioned in the release updates in my developer edition org.                                                                                               
1) Setting the email address in org wide email address and verified it .                             2)Send Case Notifications from System Address is checked to true and Enable test run to True at Release updates. 3) Now I have tried to change the owner of one of the case so I received the email from the org wide email which I set in first step.

Comment: you configured the email under `Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Addresses`?

Comment: yes . We need to configure under Special Purpose Organization-Wide Email Addresses.

Comment: Tried same still getting noreply@salesforce.com