# what should I use for the default no-reply address?

Tags: email, customsetting, org-wide-defaults

I am confused about Special Purpose [Organization-Wide Email Addresses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/362675/salesforce-spring-21-organization-wide-email-adresses).

- By design, a no-reply address is one that human beings don't check the inbox, but Salesforce requires us to [click a verification link sent to the no-reply address](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000355733&type=1). How do these two concepts make sense together?
- I tried to add an existing departmental email address to the Special Purpose addresses, but Salesforce said I can't because it's already in the User Selectable addresses. So it has to be a previously-unused address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By design, a no-reply address is one that human beings don't check the inbox, but Salesforce requires us to click a verification link sent to the no-reply address. How do these two concepts make sense together?

Just because a no-reply address isn't normally monitored by humans doesn't mean that it can't be verified by checking the inbox. How this works depends on the email system used, but it should be as simple as either temporarily enabling the inbox to receive messages, forwarding the emails to a "real" email address, or setting a whitelist for the Salesforce emails to be received.

The point of verifying an email address is to make sure you actually *control* that email address, and the only way to do that is by an email. Imagine all the shenanigans you could pull off if you could use any arbitrary address without verification.

> I tried to add an existing departmental email address to the Special Purpose addresses, but Salesforce said I can't because it's already in the User Selectable addresses. So it has to be a previously-unused address?

It just has to be a not-currently-used address. The purpose of Org-Wide Email Addresses is to allow users to send emails from specific addresses. If you can already send an email because it's user selectable, it doesn't make sense to allow that same email as a departmental one as well. If it's really meant for one department, you'll need to remove it for the organization first.

Comment: It would appear that in Winter 23, one can reuse existing org-wide addresses and make them the "default" and user-selectable. No re-verification is required if already verified.